# Lucene Index broken after LockObtainFailedException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, lucene

I'm using Lucene in asp-core project. But every 2-4 days my index is broken. So i logged the exceptions and got the following stacktrace:

> 2017-09-06 10:13:50.8338|An unhandled exception has occurred: Lock
>   obtain timed out:
>   SimpleFSLock@e:\inetpub\Static_Data\GKHUB\lucene_index\write.lock:
>   System.IO.IOException: lockFile
>   'e:\inetpub\Static_Data\GKHUB\lucene_index\write.lock' alredy
>   exists.EXCEPTION OCCURRED:Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException

After some researches i found out, that

> This exception is thrown when the write.lock could not be acquired. This happens when a writer tries to open an index that another writer already has open.[ [src](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/store/LockObtainFailedException.html) ]

So the second Update-Request couldn't update the index. But why is the whole index broken afterwards? 
My Code doesn't do anything special:

```
public void UpdateIndex(Document doc, int idToUpadate)
{
    var indexwriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, Analyzer);
    indexwriterConfig.WriteLockTimeout = 5000; // doesn't fix the problem
    using (var writer = new IndexWriter(GetLuceneDirectory, indexwriterConfig)) {
        try {
            writer.UpdateDocument(new Term("Id", idToUpadate.ToString()), doc);
            writer.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            writer.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how many updates do you have? you actually creating new instance of indexwriter on each update method, which isn't a good a idea

Comment: usually one at a time, in case of several, this error occurs. Why is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mention in the question:

> `LockObtainFailedException` is thrown when the write.lock could not be
>   acquired. This happens when a writer tries to open an index that
>   another writer already has open.

That's happening if you have multiple updates, in you code, you're creating multiple instances of the `IndexWriter` that are trying to obtain the lock on the index. You should try to re-use a single writer instead of closing and opening/creating a new one. This should solve your problem.

Also, do not forget, that

> IndexWriter instances are completely thread safe, meaning multiple
>   threads can call any of its methods, concurrently

Comment: but i have got 2 indexes... one for mediaContents and one for my products. (in different dirs) So i need at least 2 indexWriter. right? I have to pass the directory to the writer every time.

Comment: yes, in this case 2 index writers should be fine, just do not create one on each update